# Python, Kivy: How to copy to clipboard on the click of a button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, clipboard

I would like to copy a text to the clipboard with the click of a button. Example code:

**.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

sm = ScreenManager()

class main(Screen):
    def generate(self):
        text = 'Testing123456'
        #copy to clipboard

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm.add_widget(main(name='main'))

        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**.kv**

```
<main>
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Generate'
            font_size: (self.height - len(self.text) * 2) / 2
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.25, 'y': 0.1}
            on_release: root.generate()
```

There is more of my code, but I decided to remove it because that would be off-topic. Should you need the rest of my code, feel free to tell me so.

Help is appreciated!!

Comment: what did you try? Did you get error message? Show FULL error in question.

Comment: kivy documentation: [Clipboard](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.clipboard.html)

Comment: @furas, I did not get any errors, but I didn't know what to use to start with.

Comment: I would say: always start with Google. I answered your question only because I checked in  Google `kivy clipboard`. And first result was link to documentation [Clipboard](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.clipboard.html)

Comment: I am still developing that skill, I did a search on google; it seems that I had put the wrong keywords in. Anyway, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't explain what is your problem but you have all in documentation: [Clipboard](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.clipboard.html)

```
from kivy.core.clipboard import Clipboard
 
class main(Screen):
    def generate(self):
        text = 'Testing123456'
        Clipboard.copy(text)
```

And this works for me on Linux.

Answer (score -1):

If you are working on Windows OS, you can create a *nested function* in conjunction with *OS* *module* to calling a *cmd function*:

```
import os
def addToClipBoard(text):
    command = 'echo ' + text.strip() + '| clip'
    os.system(command)

a = input("Ingrese el dato:")
addToClipBoard(a)
```

You can add this function to your *event detector* of your button with *Kivy*